# Different scores for identical documents after upgrading from spring-data-elasticsearch 4.2.1 to 4.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm currently in the process of upgrading the spring boot version of my project. After upgrading from 2.5 to 2.6 a few tests started failing which deal with the retrival of elasticsearch documents. I'm trying to fetch only the highest scoring documents, but when expecting 2 identical documents, only 1 is retrieved.

After reading up on the issue I figured out that the problem comes down to the Elasticsearchindex using multiple shards, each having their own scoring logic and (probably?) the identical documents being fetched from different shards, thus resulting in different scores despite being virtually the same.

Now, can anyone tell me why this happens in the newer spring-data-elasticsearch version and if there is a setting to return it to the old functionality?

I've set up a little test project to play around with this. If anyone is interested in trying this for themselves, feel free to check it out: https://github.com/Moldavis/elasticsearch-scoring-poc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found my own answer in the spring data breaking changes documentation (duh).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.2-4.3.breaking-changes

```
search_type default value
The default value for the search_type in Elasticsearch is query_then_fetch. This now is also set as default value in the Query implementations, it was previously set to dfs_query_then_fetch.
```

The dfs_query_then_fetch option queries all shards for document and term frequency to equal out the score between different shards. This is no longer used by default, therefore the mentioned problem occurs.

It can be fixed by setting the searchtype for the query like so:

```
queryBuilder.withSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH);
```

Comment: glad you found it yourself and I don't have to dig into the changes. As written in the documentation this was changed so that the default behaviour of Spring Data Elasticsearch is the same as that of Elasticsearch itself.